# How to replicate the functionality of CSS filters with their magnitude values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

Let's say I want to apply the grayscale filter on the canvas. This is the code that I am going to use:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
  var brightness = 0.34 * data[i] + 0.5 * data[i + 1] + 0.16 * data[i + 2];
  data[i] = brightness;
  data[i + 1] = brightness;
  data[i + 2] = brightness;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it makes the image completely grayscale. What I want to do is apply all this (and other) filters with a magnitude. In CSS, I could do this:

```
.element {
  filter: grayscale(0.8);
}
```

How can I replicate this functionality in JavaScript?

Another thing that I want to know is how to create filters that behave exactly like the CSS filters. For example, two same images with `contrast(1.5)` applied to them should look exactly same irrespective of the fact that the filter was applied by CSS or the JavaScript filter that I created? Is there any resource that I can read to find out exactly how CSS manipulates a given pixel to apply a filter like contrast or brightness?

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rayon I think the cross-origin policy won't let me edit images on the canvas :)

Comment: — Take an image which is allowed...

Comment: @Rayon As far as I can tell, the image needs to be on JSFiddle for it to be editable and I don't think JSFiddle allows us to upload resources. :)

Comment: Refer http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/

Comment: @Rayon I got this error in console `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`. Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j2z0tgoy/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/j2z0tgoy/1/